# Troubles with Python regex for a column in excel

Tags: python, regex, excel

Hello I am new to Python and i have ran into a wall regarding my Python script. I am trying to use *regex* to pull names from a specific column in an excel spreadsheet. Example is finding all names that contain st. I have no problems finding the full name with my code i have just ran into problems with the regex part.

```
import re
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('NAME.xlsx') 
ex = wb['name']
fc = ex['B'] 

mo = re.compile(r"BL.*")
new = mo.search(str(fc))
```

So I named `fc` column `B` from the spreadsheet and i am trying to search all items in column `B` that starts with `BL` (once i get this to work i will work on contains whatever). I cannot seem to get it to work. it doesn't error but i am unable to print anything out. I am sure its something a newbie could easily miss but i have been trying to figure this out for a while with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Pandas.

First, import the pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then invoke the read_excel method to read your data into a dataframe. Specify the name of the sheet in the workbook that you want to read:

```
wb = pd.read_excel('NAME.xlsx', sheet_name = 'your_sheet_name_here')
```

By default, the first row of each column will become the column names in your dataframe. Since I haven't seen your data, I will assume the column of interest is called 'B'. You can extract text starting with 'BL' in column 'B' by using the `extract` method in pandas. Let's put the result of the extraction in a new column of your dataframe called 'found_it':

```
wb['found_it'] = wb['B'].str.extract(r'((BL)*)', expand = True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there a way to do this in openpyxl?